# mozila/geckodriver path for Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, rubygems

i installed ruby gem selenium-webdriver but it does not work , because it can't found geckodriver PATH.
how can i add mozila/geckodriver path to Ubuntu PATH ?

Comment: i copy this in /home directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. download driver from
   [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) /
   [chromedriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.27/)
2. extract `downloaded` file
3. move extracted file to `/usr/bin` folder

That's it.